# SQLl query to convert rows into column and get a single row for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I converted rows to column with this query

```
select 
    LAST_MOD_BY,
    (select count(*) 
     from tblALRT 
     where LAST_MOD_BY = 'USER2') 'Total Cases Worked',
    (case when STATUS_TYPE = 'Pending' then count(*) end) 'Pending' ,
    (case when STATUS_TYPE = 'Reassign' then count(*) end) 'Reassign'',
    (case when STATUS_TYPE = 'Lost' then count(*) end) 'Lost'
from 
    tblALRT 
where 
    LAST_MOD_BY = 'USER2' 
group by  
    STATUS_TYPE, LAST_MOD_BY
```

The result is:

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVddN.png)

I want the following result

[required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY1ng.png)

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using cases you can also use subqueries such as:

```
SELECT LAST_MOD_BY,
    COUNT(*) AS ‘Total Cases Worked’,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblALRT WHERE LAST_MOD_BY = ‘USER2’ AND STATUS_TYPE = ‘Pending’) AS ‘Pending’,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblALRT WHERE LAST_MOD_BY = ‘USER2’ AND STATUS_TYPE = ‘Reassign’) AS ‘Reassign’,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblALRT WHERE LAST_MOD_BY = ‘USER2’ AND STATUS_TYPE = ‘Lost’) AS ‘Lost’,
FROM tblALRT
WHERE LAST_MOD_BY = ‘USER2’
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. The only thing i added in the query is the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

I believe simply rearraging the order of your GROUP BY clause should fix your code to work as desired:

```
select LAST_MOD_BY,(select count(*) from tblALRT where 
LAST_MOD_BY='USER2'
)'Total Cases Worked',
  (case when STATUS_TYPE = 'Pending' then count(*) end) 'Pending' ,
  (case when STATUS_TYPE = 'Reassign' then count(*) end) 'Reassign',
  (case when STATUS_TYPE = 'Lost' then count(*) end) 'Lost'
  from tblALRT 
where LAST_MOD_BY='USER2' 
group by LAST_MOD_BY, STATUS_TYPE;
```

This is because the LAST_MOD_BY (user) column is really what you are grouping by. I haven't tested this, though, so if still doesn't work comment below and I'll test it out myself.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ahh shoot. Same result?